# How can I install multiple version of clang/llvm?

Tags: update-alternatives, clang

I added the repo from [llvm-apt](https://apt.llvm.org/). It contains llvm7 and llvm8. I want to install both versions. The main packages are installed fine. However, there is a problem for `libc++`, since both packages want to install libs with same names to `/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

```
 apt-file list "libc++1-7"
libc++1-7: /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libc++.so.1
libc++1-7: /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libc++.so.1.0
libc++1-7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1
libc++1-7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1.0
libc++1-7: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-7/NEWS.Debian.gz
libc++1-7: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-7/changelog.Debian.gz
libc++1-7: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-7/copyright
libc++1-7: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libc++1-7
$ apt-file list "libc++1-8"
libc++1-8: /usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/libc++.so.1
libc++1-8: /usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/libc++.so.1.0
libc++1-8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1
libc++1-8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1.0
libc++1-8: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-8/NEWS.Debian.gz
libc++1-8: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-8/changelog.Debian.gz
libc++1-8: /usr/share/doc/libc++1-8/copyright
libc++1-8: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libc++1-8
```

Is there any good way I can hack into this and use update-alternatives to maintain the symlink in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a bug in llvm-apt. Now the bug was solved. Everything is correctly labelled with `-version` now.